# Nginx-1.19.6 + Openssl 1.1.1i - Can't do SSL handshake

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

i'm trying to run a server using Nginx with sslv3 and ciphers RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5 support (i need exactly these ciphers).
I was able to do this on Ubuntu 16.04 using Openssl 1.0.2u source + last nginx version source (nginx-1.19.6). I builded Nginx using this command:

`./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-openssl=/path/to/openssl-1.0.2u --with-openssl-opt=enable-ssl3 --with-openssl-opt=enable-ssl3-method --with-openssl-opt=enable-weak-ssl-ciphers`

Nginx config i used is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3;
    ssl_ciphers RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:@SECLEVEL=0;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/server-chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/server.key;
    server_name server.name.net;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    location / {    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host \$host:\$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server \$host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

After setting up nginx config file everything worked perfectly. I was able to obtain the ssl certificate using this command from an Ubuntu 14.04 machine:

`openssl s_client -connect MyIP:443 -ssl3 -cipher RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5`.

I tryed to do the same thing building Nginx with Openssl 1.1.1i source with the same configuration options, but after setting up nginx conf file, when i try to run `openssl s_client -connect...` command, i get this error:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140420793624224:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:339:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1612540521
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

In Nginx error.log file i got this:

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141FC044:SSL routines:tls_setup_handshake:internal error) while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.1.10, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Did something change with openssl 1.1.1? Am i missing any configuration options to enable SSLv3 + RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5?
Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

In the end i was able to fix this!

I downloaded the last openssl source (1.1.1i) and the last nginx source (1.19.6).
I compiled and installed openssl with the following commands:

```
./config enable-ssl3 enable-ssl3-method enable-weak-ssl-ciphers
make
sudo make install
```

I edited openssl.cnf file (/usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf) adding

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

at the beginning of the file and adding

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = ALL:@SECLEVEL=0
```

at the bottom of the file. This enables old ciphers (i needed RC4-SHA and RC4-MD5).
Then i compiled and installed nginx with the following commands:

```
./configure --with-http_ssl_module --with-ld-opt="-L/usr/local"
make
sudo make install
```

After configuring nginx for ssl certificates i was able to get them using the `openssl s_client...` command!

Answer (score 0):

[SSL Ciphers in nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_ciphers) need to be supported by your openSSL Version. From the [openSSL Changelog of 1.0.2h and 1.1.0](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html#openssl-102):

> RC4 based libssl ciphersuites are now classed as "weak" ciphers and are disabled by default. They can be re-enabled using the enable-weak-ssl-ciphers option to Configure.

Comment: I compiled nginx with openssl using enable-weak-ssl-ciphers (wrote the full command above). I also added @SECLEVEL=0 into the ssl_chipers string. I can't really understand what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't think so, because it was linking 1.0.2 in your command and I couldn't even compile a recent nginx with this flags (due to missing `pcre` and `zlib` in my lab). I just compiled the same config (1.19.6 + openssl 1.1.1) and can also not get a result with your `-connect` from a `1.0.2g` openssl on ubuntu xenial (recent versions do not even accept `-ssl3`) - with a different error on SSL side, but the same on nginx side. Also [sslyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze/) could not find a matching cipher, what is unusual...

Comment: To fix prce and zlib just run this:
```sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev```

Comment: I linked them manually, as I compile nginx myself on a regular base. This is why I thought "this might be an easy shot" - it wasn't ;) Still got no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: Digging around from the nginx page you linked above i found this page: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html In Notes it talks about the -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=level option. I tryed using it (=0), but old ciphers where completely gone with it...